# Split the vector into equal height parts

Tags: r

I have a logical vector `y` and I want to split it into `N` parts such that each part has the same number of `TRUE` values (I do *not* care how many `FALSE` values are in each part). Specifically, I want an integer vector `b` of length `N+1` such that `b[1]=1`, `b[N+1]=length(y)+1` and `abs(sum(y[b[i]:b[i+1])-sum(y)/N)<1`.

The algorithm is trivial (use [`cumsum`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html) and [`which`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.html) in a loop) but I want to avoid the loop.

Comment: I think it would help if you could actually provide a reproducible example and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(1)
x = sample(c(T,F), 20, T)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[17] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

N = 3
y = which(x)
y[seq(1, length(y), by = length(y)/N)]
#[1]  1 10 14
```

Perhaps additionally wrap `seq` in `round`, depending on your numbers and what you want.